# Is there a way to ask the ordinal number value in English without sounding weird?

Tags: questions, ordinal-numbers

If the answer expected is *It is an amazing car*, then the question would be *How is the car?*

If the answer expected is *I got my red car* then the question would be something like *Which colour car did you get?* or *Which car did you get?*

BUT if the expected answer is *This is my third car* / *This is my ninteenth birthday*, then what would the question be precisely? How would you frame it, if possible?

To clarify the importance of the precise question: So far, the only way I know how to elicit the above mentioned answer would be to hint it in the question itself, like *Is this you twentieth birthday?*, and then they would answer *No, this is my ninteenth birthday.*

Comment: Good question, but alas, it is one that has been asked many a time before...

Comment: Actually, this was shown as the first related question, even more overwhelming than the one @AndrewLeach linked: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95184/how-would-you-phrase-questions-that-require-an-interrogative-ordinal-which-is?rq=1

Comment: A colloquial expression for this purpose seems to be the word "manieth", which isn't a proper English word though.

Comment: @oerkelens Apologies. I need to up my duplicate finding game!

Comment: @oerkelens The one I chose is the top Related question in my sidebar. Odd. It's also the ninth most-chosen target for dupes.